# Remove jsessionid cookie from static resources

Tags: tomcat, cookies

I am using tomcat 7 behind nginx. There are few static resources like css, js and few image files that are served by my app instead of nginx because their name might include version to renew itself in cache.

As you may know, **YSlow** suggests to serve static content from cookieless domain. I know some extra bytes on few files won't affect performance much but still is there any way by which I can exclude jsessionId cookie to be set on static files served by my app.

Comment: You want to prevent the client from sending the cookie to the server, or you want to prevent Nginx from forwarding the cookie to your application server?

Comment: I want to stop tomcat or my app to add cookies on static content requests.

Comment: Are you sure that the server response includes a `Set-Cookie` header? Are those static resources "inside" a protected `web-resource-collection`? If so, then the spec basically requires that the cookie be sent.